# Read Wireshark capture in Fiddler for non standard port

Tags: wireshark, fiddler

I did a network capture using Wireshark of a browsing session on a server behind a reverse proxy. The Website listens to port 105. In WireShark, I had to inform the dissector that port 105 is HTTP for it to detect the data correctly but after that, I can see it correctly.

I would like to open this log (exported as pcap) in Fiddler since it is easier to analyze but Fiddler only detects traffic from another site (that runs on port 81).

Is there any setting we can use to tell Fiddler that port 105 is HTTP traffic? How is the import packet working to detect what is HTTP and what is not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Weer](https://weerdbg.com/), it can open .pcap file.

*Disclaimer: I am the program author.*